# Apache Flink: aligning watermark among parallel tasks

Tags: java, streaming, apache-flink

We are using periodic event time window with watermark. We have currently 4 parallel tasks in our Flink App.

During the streaming process, all the 4 tasks' watermark values must be close to trigger window event.

> For example;
>
> Task 1 watermark value = 8
>
> Task 2 watermark value = 1
>
> Task 3 watermark value = 8
>
> Task 4 watermark value = 8

**Task 2 is waiting for log to update its watermark. However, the condition can occur before Task 2's update and we want to fire the window event before it.**

Is there any mechanism to align all the parallel tasks' watermarks or fire the window event without waiting for other tasks?

Comment: I does not make much sense to align watermarks across parallel tasks. The idea of watermarks is to signal that no more elements with a lower timestamp can arrive. If the one of your tasks hasn't seen a watermark of value `8` then this means that elements with a timestamp with `2-8` can still arrive. Maybe you should switch to processing time to achieve your goal. But here again, there is no synchronization between the individual tasks running on different machines.

Comment: Hi @TillRohrmann , thank you for your answer. We have a scenario like this:  Suppose that there are messages. We keyBy these messages by their sender. If there are 3 senders which are same person, we produce alert. In the example above, we can not produce alert because to produce alert the task which has watermark 2 needs to be updated. Because of the second task, window will not fired until a new log.

Comment: I think you got the concept of `keyBy` a bit wrong. If you want to look for 3 senders which are the same person, then you should `keyBy` the person and then simply use a count window to generate the alerts. Maybe you also wanna filter out duplicate senders for the same person.

Comment: But we need to consider also the event time. For example 3 senders in 10 minutes(event time not process time).

Comment: Then you can use an event time window with a custom trigger which fires when it has seen 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered in the comments by @Til Rohrmann, main answer:

> If you want to look for 3 senders which are the same person, then you
> should `keyBy` the person and then simply use a count window to
> generate the alerts. Maybe you also wanna filter out duplicate senders
> for the same person.

Followup question:

> But we need to consider also the event time. For example 3 senders in
> 10 minutes(event time not process time)

Followup answer:

> Then you can use an event time window with a custom trigger which
> fires when it has seen 3 elements.

I suppose the critical conclusion is:
If you want to trigger a count of something, keyBy that field.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old call. But [Flink 1.18](https://flink.apache.org/2023/10/24/announcing-the-release-of-apache-flink-1.18/#production-ready-watermark-alignment) made [Watermark alignment](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#watermark-alignment) something internal.

Perhaps this may still be useful for new folks getting to this question.